# По умолчанию не ставится Checkbox на false

Tags: javascript, html, css

Никак не могу сделать что б по умолчанию чекбокс был НЕ выбран. Логика кода проста, если выбран чекбокс то два поля радио становятся активными, если убрать флажек, то они стираются и не активны но по умолчанию при заходе на страницу они должны быть все пустые. Спасибо

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Блокировка поля</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <input type="checkbox" name="agree" checked="false" onclick="agreeForm(this.form)"> 
    

   <input type="radio" checked="false"  name="agree3" disabled> 
   
   <input type="radio" checked="false"  name="agree2" disabled> 

  </form>
  <script>
   function agreeForm(f) {
    // Если поставлен флажок, снимаем блокирование кнопки
    if (f.agree.checked) {
     f.agree3.disabled = 0;
     f.agree2.disabled = 0;
    }
    // В противном случае вновь блокируем кнопку
    else{
     f.agree3.disabled = 1;
     f.agree2.disabled = 1;
     f.agree3.checked = false;
     f.agree2.checked = false;
    } 
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убери атрибут checked вообще, по умолчанию чекбоксы не активны, разве что какой-то скрипт его чекает

Comment: Спасибо, работает